# Spring @EventListener annotation on two beans having the same interface

Tags: java, spring, event-listener

I'm trying to publish and process events with Spring @EventListener. I have interface that declares the method that is responsible for processing events and I have 2 different handlers that implement this interface.

Interface:

```
public interface Handler {
    void handle(EventDto eventDto);
}
```

Handlers look like this:

Handler # 1

```
@Async
@EventListener(condition = "@eventValidator.isForHandler1(#eventDto)")
public void synchronizeChannel(EventDto eventDto) {
}
```

Handler # 2

```
@Async
@EventListener(condition = "@eventValidator.isForHandler2(#eventDto)")
public void synchronizeChannel(EventDto eventDto) {
}
```

The problem that I faced is that the validator for handler 2 is never invoked *(@eventValidator.isForHandler2)*.

However, validator for first one is invoked, but the second handler takes the control and tries to process the event. It's obvious that it fails due to the fact that it just can't process not its event. Even in case validator is invoked for the event that comes to the second handler, it would definitely fail.

I tried to remove the interface and make handlers independent(without implementing anything common). It helped. But, why it doesn't work with the same interface? May it be a Spring related bug?